# image slider width wider than wrapper, wont overflow and center when its get to the proper width of the site

Tags: width, overflow, css

I am currently building a WordPress site and have a issue with a slider.

The slide image is 1200px wide but the site is 945px. I need the image to always stay centered. It's fine when the browser is stretched to over 1200px wide but as soon as you resize down to around 1100px wide and smaller the slider images don't overflow out the left side of the page, it hits the edge of the left browser and does not center anymore and pushes right so the extra part of my images should be overflowing out the browser but it's not for some reason.

Here's the image of how it's looking when the page is scrolled down, the writing should always line up on the left with the rest of the stuff like the image underneath it, there is about 100px on either side, but on the right side the image fades off so it needs to go further then the 945px width:

[image]

Here is my CSS and its the easing slider WordPress plugin:

```
section#slider-wrapper {
width:100%;
height:330px;
margin-bottom: 32px;
position: relative;
overflow: visible;
z-index: 1;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px #eee;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px #eee;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px #eee;      
background: url(images/slider-bg.jpg) #fff center repeat;       
}



#slider-wrapper #slides {
z-index:100;
height:330px;
width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
 }
 #slider-wrapper .slides_container {
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
 }
 #slider-wrapper .slides_container div.slide, #slider-wrapper .slides_container div.slide img {
width:100%;
height:330px;
display:block;
  }
  #slider-wrapper .slides_container div.slide img {
width:1200px;
height:330px;
display:block;
  }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<section id="slider-wrapper">
<div id="slides">
        <div class="slides_container">
         <!-- Easing Slider -->
             <div class="lof-container" style="height:330px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">
             <div class="lof-slidecontent" id="lofslidecontent45" style="border:0px solid #ccc;width:1200px;height:330px;">
             <div class="preload" style="padding-top:1px\9;background:url(wp-content/plugins/easing-slider/images/indicator.gif) no-repeat center center #;">

       </div>
        <div class="lof-main-outer" style="background: #;width:1200px;height:330px;">
            <ul class="lof-main-wapper">
               <li><img src="wp-content/uploads/2012/08/slide_1.jpg" style="width:1200px;" alt="" /></li>       
               <li><img src="wp-content/uploads/2012/08/slide_2.jpg" style="width:1200px;" alt="" /></li>
           </ul>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- End of Easing Slider -->       
     </div>
</div>  
<div class="clear"></div>
  </section><!-- END OF SECTION#SLIDER-WRAPPER -->
```

I have tried overflows, min width just cant seem to get it working/

Here is the jFiddle version of how it works in my browser, 
the red line never overflows.

http://jsfiddle.net/strohy85/8dQ96/

Comment: You're placing the images in a list (`UL` element, as `lof-main-wapper` class). List container has a left padding and its contents aren't centered. Try adding this CSS: `.lof-main-wapper{list-type:none;padding:0;text-align:center;}`.

Comment: Hey jay, That didnt work. I updated the jsfiddle, i left out the default CSS that the plugin is using. It already had the padding:0; for that div you suggested